# Export from sql to excel using php

Tags: php, sql, excel

I am trying to export sql data to excel using php.
This is the code:

```
<div>
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","scardma_scard","Scard2020@","scardma_scard_platform");
    $query = 'SELECT ut.id, ut.nom, ut.prenom FROM utilisateurs ut WHERE ut.id_societe ='.$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
?>
<table style="display:none;" border="2px solid black">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Url</th>
    </tr>
    
</table>
<?php 
    if ($query == true) {
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=exportfile.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
    }
?>
```

It works fine on the local server, but does not work on the live server, and nothing is downloaded.

Any help ?

Comment: You've already sent headers when displaying `<div>`, `<table>` and any output. Your local server may be buffering output and that why it manages to change the headers *"after sending"* some outputs

Comment: Note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injections and you should consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: `$query` is a non empty string, it will always have a [truthy value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Based on the above code, it's a mystery as to where the exporting actually happens, there's no logic for converting the SQL results to Excel and saving it as `exportfile.xls`. In any case, unless you intend to use a library for generating said Excel files, you're probably easier and better off simply exporting to CSV and importing it with Excel.